# How to do this test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose I have a sample $\{(x_{1i}, x_{2i}, \dots, x_{mi}), i=1,\dots, n\}$of $m$ unknown random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_m$.

How can I test if $X_1 = X_2 =\dots = X_m$?

Furthermore, if there is a nonrandom explanatory variable $Y$ such that $Y=y_j$ for $X_j, j=1, \dots, m$, how can I test if $Y$ has an influence on the difference between $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_m$?

Answer (score 1):

The first question is addresed by one-way ANOVA (between- or within-subjects, depending on whether your $m$ samples are independent or linked).

Are the values of your explanatory variable pairwise comparable? If they are, you could, for example, reorder your samples in such a way that $y_1\leq\dots\leq y_m$ and use Jonckheere trend test to check if $med X_1 \leq \dots \leq med X_m$.

Comment: by "between- or within-subjects, depending on whether your m samples are independent or linked", do you mean paired or non-paried t tests?

Comment: WHich R functions to perform the two tasks?

Comment: No, it's not about t-test, these are just the variants of ANOVA. The difference between them the same as the difference between paired and non-paired t-tests. For example, if $X_{ij}$ is the blood pressure of the $i$th human participant under $j$th condition, then your samples are linked and you use within-subject ANOVA; if all the groups consist of different people, you use between-subjects ANOVA.

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/ANOVA/ - R realizations for different types of ANOVA, just find yours
Use jonckheere.test from clinfun package for the second task.